# Не могу понять команду от systemd?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos, systemd

journalctl --since "tomorrow"

По идеи показать журналы с завтрашнего дня. Как то нелогично получается.
Подскажите в чём суть команды с ключём tomorrow?